# Ajax refreshing on itself with include php

Tags: php, ajax

Ok basically here is my problem and I can't find anything about it on this site or any site. I am using Ajax for refreshing a include php file and its keeps refreshing on itself.Basically the first refresh is fine 10 seconds then this happens the second refresh is 5 seconds while refreshing on itself, then the next about 2 seconds doing same thing, and goes down to the 1 second. I don't know what is wrong why its doing this.

This is the code for refreshing. I am not doing the rest of the code. I know this is where the problem is because it causes the refreshing itself.

```
<script>
$("#active").load("active.phps");
setInterval(function(){
  $("#active").load("active.php");
}, 10000);
</script>
```

Anyone can help I would be grateful. This is to help tell what friends you have online, and with this it slows down performance on my site and on my computer.

Comment: is your script inside the element with the id active? and if yes why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the added lines to the beginning and end of your script:

```
    $(function() {
       $("#active").load("active.phps");
        setInterval(function(){
           $("#active").load("active.php");
         }, 10000);
    });
```

this runs the scriptafter everything is finished loading. So it waits basically.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked like a charm. There is no refreshing on itself now. My site is running alot smother and my computer is not getting all lagged up.

Answer (score 1):

I think that problem could be in time of ajax loading, method is probably called properly but there are delays from ajax loading. Maybe you shoul consider using setTimeout?

Simple example:

```
$(function() {
function loadPage() {
   $("#active").load("active.phps");
   setTimeOut(loadPage, 10000);
}
setTimeOut(loadPage, 10000);
$(function() {
```